# Cannot install updates

Tags: updates

Can someone tell me how to select one of these drives. Which one is more appropriate?

Screenshot on package installation:

[image: Screenshot on package installation]

Screen shot after selecting `/dev/sda/`:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, you would select `/dev/sda`, unless you know/have been told that you have to select `/dev/sda5`.

Therefore, it is probably best to select `/dev/sda` unless you have a very specific setup (which would have never warranted this question).

Select the menu item with your <kbd>SPACE</kbd> key, and then hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to proceed with the install.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer.  But i tried selecting that i i get another message which seems i never selected any drive (see edited post). How do i make sure it is selected. I used the arrow-up/down keys to leave the red triangle in the box but it seems that wasn't a selection method?

Comment: Press the SPACE button to select it.